# Partial permutation of time sequence data that keep order of events

Tags: permutations, variance, order-statistics, time-series

Suppose you have sequence S of N elements that are descending ordered by time. How many ways can you take K element subsets from S preserving time descending ordering?

example for sequence S={A,B,C,D,E,F}

```
k=2
subsequences=[AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, BC, BD, BE, BF, CD, CE, CF, DE, DF, EF]
result=15
```

Wrong sequences (not descending ordered by time) are BA, CA, DA, DC and so on.

```
k=3
subsequences=[ABC, ABD, ..., ACD, ACE, ..., AEF, ..., DEF]
result=(n-2)+(n-3)+(n-4)+(n-5)    # AB_ + AC_ + AD_ + AE_ 
            +(n-3)+(n-4)+(n-5)    #     + BC_ + BD_ + BE_
                  +(n-4)+(n-5)    #.          + CD_ + CE_
                        +(n-5)    #                 + DE_
      =4(n-5)+3(n-4)+2(n-4)+(n-2)
      =20
```

I have tried for `k=4` but I don't see any pattern and it seems to be so many possible results. I have tried with some variations of permutation and by trying to write the formula down, but I can't get it.

Target is to calculate for example how many 10 element subsequences can you get from 200 element sequence.

I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get ${N \choose k}$ such sequences, because that is the number of $k$-element subsets of an $N$-element set. Each subset corresponds to just 1 order preserving sequence: Just order the elements in the subset as you require them to be 'right'.

Comment: I do not want to generate all of subsequences and then order and count uniqe, because there would be so many of them. I just need a number of possible solutions. Your formula gives me all possible subsequences regardless of the order. It gives me for S=[a,b,c], k=3, result=[abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cab] and [acb, bac, bca, cab, cab] are not solutions I'm looking for.

Comment: No, that's not true. In the examples you gave in the problem statement, we have $N=6$ (S has 6 elements), and for $k=2$ you found $15$ solutions. My formula gives the same result ${6 \choose 2}=15$. For $k=3$ you find $20$ solutions, my formula says  ${6 \choose 3}=20$. In the example in your above comment, we have $N=3$, $k=3$ and again my formula says there is ${3 \choose 3}=1$ correct sequence.
It seems you misunderstand what I wrote.

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right. I completely missed what it means 'the order of selection does not matter' in combinations.